# Is it appropriate to ask questions that involve eztz/eztz-cli on the site?

Tags: support

I have a problem which involves interaction of eztz-cli with the tezos node. Is it appropriate to ask questions about the eztz library on the site?

Comment: That's a good meta-question. The same goes for questions about Tezbox, Galleon, tzscan.io, and the many other ancillary systems that build on the core Tezos functionality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My name is Robert Cartaino; I am the Director of New Community Development for the Stack Exchange Network.

I am not specifically familiar with the products you mentioned, but generally speaking, the tools and products used in direct relation to the Tezos community **should be on topic for this site.**

Be as inclusive as reasonable in your scope. There are certain *types* of question which may not work here (polls, product recommendations, issues of protracted discussions or debate), but anything about Tezos and related projects should be fair game here (watch for spam and astroturfing content).

Where we typically draw that line is when a question becomes **only *coincidentally* related** to the subject of Tezos. It's called the "favorite softdrink of programmers" problem, and it's when someone asks (for example) for a reliable hard drive to run a Tezos node, or a general programming syntax question, or how to deal with a legal issue related to a Tezos transaction gone bad </example>. The user may have encountered these problems while engaging in Tezos-related activities, but such questions are not directly related to the *subject* of Tezos itself.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. To me that implies that the `eztz` library is well within scope.

Comment: Robert, It is called “programmers soft drink”? I thought it is called “boat programming question”.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... Only if you don't want anybody to know what you're talking about. Boat Programming is an old meme ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about)) which includes an element of parody asking a question in a cheeky or flippant context. Not what I meant here.

Answer (score 6):

Eztz is absolutly Tezos related.
It is a Javascript API library written for Tezos.

Answer (score 5):

I think a good way to think about the scope is:

- is it a question a developer would encounter in the course of their work?
- is the question sufficiently specific to the Tezos ecosystem that it's more likely to get an answer here then in another forum. For example, a generic question about OCaml might be better on Stackoverflow, but a question about a Tezos specific library would be better served here.

In this case, the answer would be that yes, eztz related questions are completely in scope.